# How can a class know who called its method?

Tags: c++, methods, global, state

Currently I create a new instance of the class for each code that uses it. The constructor takes a string name, so I know inside the class, who called my methods.

```
class Log {
public:
    Log(std::string Name) : name(Name) {}
    void Print(std::string Message) {
        std::cout << name << " said " << Message << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string name;
};
```

This example class is used by a range of modules, which derive from an abstract type.

```
class Module {
public:
    Module(std::string Name) : log(new Log(Name)) {}
    virtual void Update() = 0;
private:
    Log *log;
};

class Renderer : public Module {
public:
    void Update() {
        log->Print("Hello World!");
    }
};

Renderer renderer("Renderer");
renderer.Update(); // "Renderer says Hello World!"
```

But now, I want to share the same instance of `Log` for all modules. How can I do this and still distinct from where method calls come from?

Background: There are plenty of modules and they make use of two types of classes. First, managers that are shared globally among modules. Second, helpers such as the example class above which are created separately for each module. But I want to find a single abstraction of both for a simpler design. Think of a logging helper that should color messages of different modules in different, evenly distributed, colors. Such a helper need to share state among all modules.

Comment: It's not a good idea but you can try this: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Backtraces.html

Comment: You can't. And for that reason we use access modifiers.

Comment: Can't the modules just tell the logger which module they are? Or if it's just the colour that's changing, which colour to use?

Comment: @TomaszKłak I didn't meant some kind of reflection or backtracing, but a design inside C++ that solves my problem.

Comment: @JosephMansfield They could. Something like `log->Print(name, "Hello World!");`. But I am looking for a way to put that logic either in the base `Module` class, or in the `Log` class.

Comment: add a helper that stores the string and forwards to your logger?

Comment: @danijar Well I definitely don't think it should go in the `Log` class. Classes shouldn't be aware of who is calling them. As long as the calling code complies with the class's interface, that's all that should matter.

Comment: @Yakk That's a possible solution, could you write that as answer, please? I'm also interested in different approaches though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the process by mkaing a few changes to the `Log` class to have it call the global log functions instead. This reduce or eliminate extensive changes to how the logging is currently being used.

```
class Log {
public:
    explicit Log(const std::string& name) : name(name) {}
    void Print(const std::string& message) const {
        GlobalLogPrint(name, message);
    }

private:
    const std::string name;
};
```

You can continue to dynamically allocate instances of the `Log` object or you can use composition.

```
class Module {
public:
    explicit Module(const std::string& name) : log(name) {}
    virtual void Update() = 0;
protected:
    Log log;
};

class Renderer : public Module {
public:
    void Update() {
        log.Print("Hello World!");
    }
};
```

Comment: Is it possible to embed the `Log` class into the global on?

Comment: Only if you change the `Log` class to not call the global one otherwise you end up with a circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're wanting. Try this:

```
class Module
{
public:
    Module(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    void Update()
    {
        VUpdate(name);
    }

private:
    virtual void VUpdate(const std::string &name) = 0;

protected:
    static Log *log;

private:
    std::string name;
};

class Renderer : public Module
{
private:
    virtual void VUpdate(const std::string &name)
    {
        log->Print(name, "Hello World!");
    }
};

Log *Module::log = new Log();
```

Your logger will have to change to accept the name of the caller in its `Print` member.

Comment: Do you think there is a way without passing `name` explicitly every time?

Comment: Not really. If you want the `Log` instance to be shared by all the potential callers, then it must be variable. *Somehow*, `Log` must be told who is making the call.

Comment: Probably, I'd take `name` out of the `Module` class and just use a macro instead.